# Using an async function for a route gives me a 404

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm running an express server trying to use Outlooks API with node, 
The routes are now using `async` and I copied a snippet from the docs:

The handling of the route:

```
const handle = {};
handle['/mail'] = mail;
```

and the function is:

```
async function mail(response, request) {
    let token;

    try {
        token = await getAccessToken(request, response);
    } catch (error) {
        response.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
        });
        response.write('<p> No token found in cookie!</p>');
        response.end();
        return;
    }

    console.log('Token found in cookie: ', token);
    const email = getValueFromCookie(
        'node-tutorial-email',
        request.headers.cookie
    );
    console.log('Email found in cookie: ', email);

    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    response.write('<div><h1>Your inbox</h1></div>');

    // Create a Graph client
    const client = microsoftGraph.Client.init({
        authProvider: done => {
            // Just return the token
            done(null, token);
        }
    });

    try {
        // Get the 10 newest messages
        const res = await client
            .api('/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages')
            .header('X-AnchorMailbox', email)
            .top(10)
            .select('subject,from,receivedDateTime,isRead')
            .orderby('receivedDateTime DESC')
            .get();

        console.log(`getMessages returned ${res.value.length} messages.`);
        response.write(
            '<table><tr><th>From</th><th>Subject</th><th>Received</th></tr>'
        );
        res.value.forEach(message => {
            console.log('  Subject: ' + message.subject);
            const from = message.from ? message.from.emailAddress.name : 'NONE';
            response.write(
                `<tr><td>${from}` +
                `</td><td>${message.isRead ? '' : '<b>'} ${message.subject} ${
        message.isRead ? '' : '</b>'
        }` +
                `</td><td>${message.receivedDateTime.toString()}</td></tr>`
            );
        });

        response.write('</table>');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`getMessages returned an error: ${err}`);
        response.write(`<p>ERROR: ${err}</p>`);
    }

    response.end();
}
```

It should be working... I don't see any errors there. Why am I getting a 404?

Comment: I ended up re-writing it as 
`app.get('/mail', mail)` and moved it below the function. That seems to work although I'm getting a new error: `Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): TypeError: response.writeHead is not a function` I'll look into this and update if I find a solution.

Comment: Alright, I solved it. I just wrapped the function: `app.get('/mail', async function mail(request, response) {.....}`

I'm honestly still a little confused about the origin of the error though... I thought the promise rejection was handled with `catch`?